# Perceptron learning - most important feature

Tags: java, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, perceptron

For one of my assignments in my AI class we were tasked with creating a perceptron learning implementation of the Widrow Hoff delta rule.  I've coded this implementation in java:

The following github link contains the project:
https://github.com/dmcquillan314/CS440-Homework/tree/master/CS440-HW2-1

The issue that I'm having is not with the creation of the perceptron.  That is working fine.

In the project after training the perceptron I then applied an unclassified dataset to the perceptron to then learn the classifications of each input vector.  This also worked fine.

My issue pertains to learning which feature of the inputs is the most important.

For example, if the feature set within each input vector was color, car model, and car make and we wanted to classify which feature was the most important.  How would one go about doing so.

My original understanding of this led me to believe that calculating the correlation coefficient the value of that feature for each input and the classification vector that is produced.  However, this turned out to be a false assumption.

Is there some other way that the most important feature can be learned?

**EDIT**

Sample weight vector:

( -752, 4771, 17714, 762, 6, 676, 3060, -2004, 5459, 9591.299, 3832, 14963, 20912 )

Sample input vectors:

(55, 1, 2, 130, 262, 0, 0, 155, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0)

(59, 1, 3, 126, 218, 1, 0, 134, 0, 2.2, 2, 1, 6, 1)

(45, 1, 2, 128, 308, 0, 2, 170, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0)

(59, 1, 4, 110, 239, 0, 2, 142, 1, 1.2, 2, 1, 7, 1)

The last element is the classification.

I will post an answer here when I find one.  So far I believe that the answer given by the instructor is inaccurate.

Comment: seems you know a lot about perceptron, do you have any insight with regards to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577662/application-of-delta-rule-to-feature-vectors-perceptron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a lot simpler than I originally thought.  The answer/process is as follows:

Given a set of input vectors such as the following:

[1,0,1,0], [0,1,0,1]

The data is already constrained between 0 and 1 to minimize the variance. However, in the case of my data I have something more like the following:

[0,145,0,132],[0,176,0,140]

This causes the variance in some input features to be much larger and you would therefore not be able to use the weight vector as an indicator of feature importance.  Therefore, in order for the weight vector to be an indicator of importance we much normalize the data first by dividing by the feature max.

For the above set that would be: [0,176,0,140]

This would result in a set of uniform feature vectors and would also result in the weight vector being an indicator of feature importance.

Answer (score 3):

The importance of a feature is captured by computing how much the learned model depends on a feature *f*.

A perceptron is a simple feed-forward neural network, and for a neural network (which is a real-valued nonlinear function), dependency corresponds to the partial derivative of output function with respect to *f*.

The relative importance of a feature is proportional to its average absolute weight on a trained perceptron. This is not always true for neural networks in general. For instance, this need not hold true for multi-layer perceptrons.

For more details (typing the exact formula here will be a notational mess), look at [sections 2 and 3 of this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.5556.pdf). I believe equation (8) (in section 3) is what you are looking for.

There, the score is a summation over multiple learners. If yours is a single-layer perceptron, the function learned is a single weight vector

**w** = (*w1*, *w2*, ... *wn*)

Then, the *average absolute weight* I mention at the beginning is simply the absolute weight |*wi*| of the *i*-th feature. This seems too simple a measure to be ranking the importance of features, right? But ... if you think about it, an n-dimensional input **x** gets transformed to **w** . **x** (the vector dot product). That is, the *i*-th weight *wi* fully controls how much the input changes along one dimension of the vector space.

By the way, in most (if not all) classifiers, the feature weight is itself the measure of its importance. It's just that the weights are computed in more complicated ways for most other classifiers.

Comment: After reading over the paper, it seems that it doesn't find the most important feature.  It seems to allow the use of importance on each feature.  Could you elaborate if this is incorrect?

Comment: They use the feature importance to bias the initial weights in the first layer of their multi-layer perceptron. But in your case, you already have a learned single-layer perceptron. Thus, you have the weights. Using these weights, you can compute the values. Since there are no more layers in your perceptron, there is nothing more to be done.

Comment: I've added the resultant weight vector from the training to the post.  I'm trying to understand what the parts of this equation are.  I know that w is obviously the weight vector, however it says that L is the learner and there is only one learner in this case.  Therefore, I believe there would be only one summation which is essentially the weight vector.  How does this show the most important feature?  I think that's where I'm getting a bit lost.

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly then you're saying the maximum weight value is the most important feature?  However in this assignment the answer was the one with the lowest weight of -2004.  I've added a couple example inputs to the post above.

Comment: The absolute weight, i.e. the absolute value of the weight should determine the most important feature. I am now very interested in hearing why the feature with value -2004 is the right answer. To the best of my knowledge, it shouldn't be.

Comment: Agreed, we don't exactly have the best professor for this course and he is reluctant to provide any insight as to how or why that is the most important feature.  Wasn't mentioned in the lectures either...  His hint was the following: "it is not necessarily the one with the largest absolute-valued weight".  That's why I'm getting so confused on this one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47365/discussion-between-dmcqu314-and-chthonic-project)

Comment: @ChthonicProject seems you know a lot about perceptron, do you have any insight with regards to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577662/application-of-delta-rule-to-feature-vectors-perceptron)

Answer (score 0):

Because Perceptron Learning, especially Multi-layer Perceptron Network, is a black box algorithm where the weights and the activations are affected partially by some or almost or all features, we have not had tools to extract directly the feature importance yet, while it is easy for tree-based models to do that. However, we can use the PERMUTATION IMPORTANCE method that is introduced here: https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-importance-with-neural-network-346eb6205743